# react-native-detox building on android blocked by proguard

Tags: react-native, detox

I've been trying to use detox to test e2e. 
RN 0.57.0

I followed the integration steps for android but I'm blocked on trying to compile the project. 
`detox build -c android.emu.debug`

It builds perfectly when I run the normal `./gradlew assembleRelease` command.

```
    Note: there were 27 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
...
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
...
Warning: android.support.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$UnsafeAtomicHelper$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
...
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: there were 24 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 14 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForReleaseAndroidTest'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 30s
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^
```

Perhaps detox requires another proguard file?

----UPDATE----
Here is my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-zendesk-support')
    implementation project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-calendar-events')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2"

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-photo-view')
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
      implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
      implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1') {
          force = true
      }
    }
    implementation(project(':react-native-notifications')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging'
    }
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2") {
        implementation project(':react-native-notifications')
    }
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')

    androidTestImplementation(project(":detox"))
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

Not sure if the react native dependencies make a difference...
Perhaps there is a mismatch in versions?

Comment: can you post your dependencies in `build.gradle` in android folder?

Comment: @vk.4884 updated! sorry about that!

Comment: @Henry is detox compatible with RN 0.57? I have a lot of problems with iOS. Dunno if it happened to you also.